# How do I implement a python dictionary with combinations so that it returns keys as indices and values as the value of the element?

Tags: python, arrays, combinations, python-itertools

I'm trying to find 2 numbers(n=2) in the array that add up to 3 and print the tuple. In this example the output should be {0:1,1:2}. Currently I have the output to be true or false but I want it to return a tuple that is part of a dictionary and I'm not sure how to implement it.

```
import itertools
dict={}
def findWithSum(arr,value,n=2):
        combinations=list(itertools.combinations(arr, n))
        for t in combinations:
                
                if sum(t) == value:
                        return True
        return False     

arr= [1,2,3]
n=2
print(findWithSum(arr,3,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic structure of your original solution works fine.  To change the output into the form you're looking for, use `enumerate` to get tuples of the indices along with the values, make sure to `sum` just the values, and then return a `dict` of the pairs if the sum matches.

```
from itertools import combinations

def find_with_sum(arr: list[int], value: int, n: int = 2) -> dict[int, int]:
    for t in combinations(enumerate(arr), n):
        if sum(val for i, val in t) == value:
            return dict(t)
    return {}

print(find_with_sum([1, 2, 3], 3, 2))
# {0: 1, 1: 2}
```

Note that the built-in function `dict` very conveniently turns the combination `t` into the exact dict you want (it takes an iterable of tuples and gives you a dict with the first tuple element as the key and the second element of the value), but you can't use that function if you assign the name `dict` to something else:

```
dict={}  # never do this!
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import itertools
dict={}
st=set()
def findWithSum(arr,value,n=2):
        combinations=list(itertools.combinations(arr, n))
        i=0
        for t in combinations:
            st.add(t[0])
        key=0
        for i in st:
            dict[key]=i
            key+=1
        return dict

arr= [1,2,3]
n=2
print(findWithSum(arr,3,2))
```

Comment: you can use these,it will give you output like {0:1,1:2}

Comment: This function has a pretty serious bug.  Try calling it multiple times with different inputs.  Do you get the results you expect each time?

Comment: thank you for mentioning bug, Please add a input example, It would help me for solving bug @Samwise

Comment: try adding the line `print(findWithSum([2, 3, 4], 5, 2))` to the end of this code (right after `print(findWithSum(arr,3,2))`).  The output should be `{0: 1, 1: 2}` followed by `{0: 2, 1: 3}`, right?  What is it instead?